# Can matlab catch signals from linux? (e.g. SIGIO)

Tags: matlab, kill, signals, try-catch

Does matlab have the capability to catch signals from linux?

For example, the signal `SIGIO (29)` can be sent to a process with a lease on a file when another process attempts to open that file. From my testing, when I try `kill -s 29 pid`, where `pid` is the process ID of a running matlab window, the matlab process is killed. Similarly, `kill -SIGIO pid` causes the matlab process to die.

Is there some way to catch these (i.e. not have matlab die)?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a MEX module in C that handles this signal, and maybe sets a flag somewhere that can be queried later from Matlab.